# Comparar cadenas de un List<String> y devolver la cadena con más minúsculas

Tags: java

Estoy atascado con un ejercicio, el enunciado es:

> Dada una lista de String buscar la cadena que tiene un mayor número de caracteres
>   en minúscula. Implementar (JAVA) una solución iterativa usando While.

Alguien me puede echar una mano? No consigo acabarlo, y tampoco sé si voy bien encaminado... Aquí abajo os dejo lo que tengo hecho. Un saludo y gracias de antemano

```
    List<String>lowerCase = Arrays.asList("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m",
              "n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z");

    List<String>l = Arrays.asList("Lavanderia", "Colegio", "Autobus");

}

// PI1.1 : 
// Dada una lista de String buscar la cadena que tiene un mayor número de caracteres
// en minúscula.


// a) Solución iterativa - WHILE
public static String buscaCad(List<String>l) {

    String res = "";
    Integer tam = l.size()-1;
    char a;

    while( tam >= 0) {

        String cadena = l.get(tam) ;
        Integer indiceCadena = cadena.length()-1;
        a = cadena.charAt(indiceCadena);

        Integer cont = 0;

            while(indiceCadena>=0) {
                if(Character.isLowerCase(a)) {
                    cont++;
                }

                indiceCadena--;
            }


        tam--;
    }
    return res;

}
```

Comment: Puedes usar el metodo "isLowerCase(Char)" e ir acumulando un contador. Al final el contador mayor sera el de la palabra con mas minusculas.

Comment: Yo crearía un array de enteros del tamaño del listado para guardar el número de minúsculas de cada frase. Después, dentro del while con el que recorres las frasees, tienes que hacer otro while para recorrer letra a letra cada frase y cada vez que encuentres una minúscula, incrementar la variable del array de enteros. Yo usaría un for para recorrer las frases, así con la i que usas como contador la usas también para moverte por el array de enteros

Comment: Okey, ya tengo la condicion isLowerCase y el acumulador, pero como hago para relacionar ese acumulador con cada cadena? Me refiero a que yo tengo que devolver la cadena cuyo acumulador sea mayor, pero no sé como relacionar el acum con las cadenas...

Comment: Bien. Haces lo que te dijo Pablo Simon y guardas el total de ese contador en una variable auxiliar y la cadena relacionada. Cuando terminas de correr la siguiente cadena, comparas el total nuevo con dicha variable auxiliar, si es mayor actualizas la variable auxiliar y la cadena, y si es menor sigues con la siguiente. Asi hasta terminar de recorrer todas las cadenas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrias encapsular el método para contar minúsculas en una función aparte, eso lo hace más legible y no tendrás iteraciones anidadas. Luego iteras una a una el arreglo de palabras guardando la que se adapte mejor en un registro junto con el contador máximo. Aunque en tu programa debes utilizar *while* puedes usar como referencia este ejemplo.

```
public class lista {

    public static int contarMinus(String input) {
        int cont = 0;
        for ( int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++ ) {
             char ch = input.charAt(i);
             if(Character.isLowerCase(ch)) cont++;
        }
        return cont;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int max_count = -1;
        String palabra_mayor = "";
        int contador;
        String[] palabras = { "Lavanderia", "Colegio", "Autobus" };
        for(int i = 0; i < palabras.length; i++) {
            contador = contarMinus(palabras[i]);
            if(contador > max_count) {
                max_count = contador;
                palabra_mayor = palabras[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("La cadena con mas letras minusculas es " + palabra_mayor + " con " + max_count + " letras.");
    }

}
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! Ahora lo adaptaré a como me lo piden a mí